# Why was my comment removed? Are we not allowed to answer OPs questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments

I answered OP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54512397/5159168) that I noticed my mistake which was that my code outputted a string and not an array and I did that before OP even commented.
Why was that comment removed?
Are we not even allowed to answer OPs questions anymore?!

It was not rude, it's not unfriendly, it certainly is still needed since OP did not even notice that I already had edited my answer before he posted his question.

Comment: When you already changed your answer, then what is the comment good for?

Comment: @BDL Well OP apparently did not even notice it. Answering a question asked to you should not be too much to ask. Or is it?

Comment: It was probably removed because someone flagged as "no longer needed". If your comment pointed to changes in your answer, then it was no longer needed, and the flag was honored.

Comment: How do you know op hasn't read your comment already? For all we know, op might have flagged it as no longer needed after reading it. Also: What exactly did you write in the comment?

Comment: Yet again. Is it too much to ask that you can answer OPs questions directly aimed at you?

Comment: OP has not been logged in since I posted the comment. I can't remember it word by word. But something like: *I notice that too. I already edited my answer before you posted your comment*. Or perhaps *I noticed my mistake...*

Comment: This reads like an attempt to vent frustration by someone who is experienced with Stack Overflow and meta and thus really carefully redacted their meta post :) You know how comment flagging and deletion works, the fact that this happened should not surprise you. The question is: does this frequently happen to you?

Comment: @Gimby I don't usually go back and make sure my comments are still there. But this comment was removed 5-10 minutes after I posted it and has not been seen by OP. That is a bit annoying. I think we should hunt down the guilty and use good old "tar and feather". What do you think?

Comment: _Is it too much to ask that you can answer OPs questions directly aimed at you?_ You can answer comments, and post comments. But those comments can be flagged anyway. Do you expect mods to check if the all the participants have logged in since, and if it appears that they read all the comments in posts they are involved with before acting on a flag? The comment was no longer needed. Someone flagged, a mod honored. Nothing else going on. Post a comment again, leave a note in your question identifying the correction, (so if the other user comes back can see your changed answer), or move on.

Comment: @yivi Yes. Quite frankly I think the mod should do that **or** leave comments that is answers to direct questions alone. I understand that there is lots of flags and you can't spend too much time on every single flag but in my opinion the flag was wrong and to just be trigger happy and click delete is also wrong. But that is my opinion.

Comment: The appropriate place to note a bug in a previous answer and tell readers you've fixed it is the edit description, in my opinion. You can comment and ping someone if you want to make sure they notice, but only for that purpose, and flagging such a comment as no longer needed after you've noticed is appropriate, and mods will probably honor those flags.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Your not following what happened. Since the edit was done in the five minute window no notice is made that the answer has been edited. OP obviously didn't notice it. Almost an hour goes by and I notice I have a comment to edit my answer to output an array,  which has already been done. **I ping OP** just as you write, but someone flags my comment/answer to OPs commet pretty much immediately. Which means my ping is not reaching the destination.

Comment: @Andreas You can't expect the mods to check if the OP has logged in and checked the comments, that's three extra clicks (go to Q+A in new tab, go to OP, click) per NLN flag. Mods assume the comment has been read. At max you can say it shouldn't have been flagged yet, but often enough this is all fine, the OP has already accepted an answer so he's often not returning soon and already has an answer he's happy with.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Mods are not expected to check if OP has been logged etc. However, I think they should at least **check that the "no longer needed" flag is coming from the same user the comment is addressed to**. E.g. *if Andreas flags this comment of mine as "no longer needed", a mod should be aware that this comment is pinging ErikvonAsmuth, not Andreas, and ignore the flag (for now\*)*. AFAIK flags are not anonymous, mods can see which user raised the flag and checking if it matches the \@pinged user requires no additional clicks at all.

Comment: ("for now" here meaning "until \@pinged user has made clear via other comments or edits or actions that they have already seen the comment, or a prudent amount of time has passed and it no longer applies or it can be assumed that the \@pinged user is just ignoring said comment")

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth yet again you miss important points. You missed ***or leave comments that is answers to direct questions alone.*** This means OP asked for clarification/modification of my answer. If I answer this comment, it is a vital part of the conversation and answer

Comment: @Andreas That's not a thing. If someone asks a question, and you answer it, and it's not essential to the Q&A chain, they're both no longer needed. If it was a real question, it should've been asked as such. Comments are for clarification and constructive criticism, not Q&A. We certainly should not leave a comment alone just because it's an answer to a no longer needed question. Generally, if there's a large thread you should use a custom flag to make sure both questions and answers are cleaned up at once, though, but for only 2 comments separate flags works.

Comment: Anyway, the only comments that are _not_ no longer needed are the ones providing valuable information to future readers, e.g. those that address issues to a question or answer that haven't been addressed in the question or answer itself. These comments clearly don't meet that criteria. I can't reasonably take you serious if you say that the fact that you changed the answer within the grace period is _a vital part of the answer_ without any explanation about how it contributes to the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Comments disappear all the time. And they are mostly there so users can improve posts, not for general communication between users.

Someone commented, and you improved the post: mission accomplished.

Since the other user already knew that there was a problem in your answer, I'm not sure what to they gain by reading your *"I'm aware of this problem and fixed it already".*

Someone must have seen the comments and the corrections and flagged. A mod obliged and honored the flags, correctly.

Complaints about deleted comments get tiresome. Complaints about of comments deleted *early* are a bit much, in my opinion.

To answer your question directly:

> *Are we not allowed to answer OPs questions?"*

Yes, we can reply to other user's comments. But comments can be flagged and deleted anyway. What you are not entitled to is the guarantee that your comment wont be deleted until certain user or users have read it.

Comments that refer to past versions of a post are by definition no longer needed.

Comment: *Someone commented, and you improved the post: mission accomplished.* Incorrect. **I improved, and OP commented after asking to do what I already had done**. *Complaints about deleted comments get tiresome. Complaints about of comments deleted early are a bit much, in my opinion.* Then maybe the moderation should be done in a different way? There wouldn't be complaints if it was done in such a way that people approved with it.

Comment: What you personally do not approve is not equivalent with "what people do not approve". For example, I approve the deletion of these comments when they are flagged. I'm less excited about comment deletion complaints. I believe experienced users should embrace the nature of comments on this site, and accept that most of them are liable to be deleted without notice.

Comment: And your comment here here only points out that your deleted comment was even more useless for future visitors. The change had already been implemented. You should have pinged the asker (as you did), and flag _their_ comment as NLN. And move on.

Comment: You can't seem to hold the line buddy. *Complaints about deleted comments get tiresome.* And *What you personally do not approve is not equivalent with "what people do not approve"* does not add up. On one hand you say there are many complaints on deleted comments, and on the other hand you say that nobody complains.

Answer (score 9):

Sigh. Someone flagged it.

Here is the whole comment exchange, now deleted:

[image]

We have many users who are obsessed with cleaning up what they perceive as "noise" in the comments. Since you had already edited the answer accordingly, your comment reply got flagged as essentially being obsolete. Appearing to be a valid flag, I complied and removed it.

After this Meta question was posted, another moderator removed the original comment to which you were replying. That one should have been flagged originally at the same time as your response, but for some reason, it wasn't. And when moderators are responding to comment flags, we don't always click through to the post to read all of the comments. Personally, I usually try to do this so I can do a better job of cleaning up, but apparently I didn't do it this time.

As others have said, the official line here is that comments are ephemeral, that they can go away at any time. I don't care to get into it now, so let's just say that I am only in partial agreement with that. In any case, I do absolutely agree that anything *important* in comments should always be incorporated into the post proper (for more reasons than just ephemerality). You did that here, so you were doing everything right.

The flagger wasn't wrong, either. The comment had ostensibly served its purpose, you'd put the information into the answer, and so it didn't need to be there anymore.

The biggest issue with overzealous deletion of "obsolete" comments is that, as in this case, the user to whom you were replying may not have noticed the update of your answer. This is especially a problem for new users (again, as in this case), who aren't as familiar with how the site operates, and may not know to continually monitor existing answers for updates.

I would prefer that people didn't flag comments like this until they were at least several days old, ensuring that an interested party would have ample time to notice. [Don't Panic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379787) makes a valid point in reminding us that we're here for the long haul, "to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming", and that "helping the OP is [only] a nice side effect". He's right, of course, and I one-hundred percent agree with this logic. But it *is* a nice side effect, and where the two goals don't conflict, we should be helpful.

And in cases where the noise is only a whisper, well, it'll take some work to convince me that they're worth flagging at all. I'd rather spend time dealing with real problems: comment threads that have more than 10 comments posted, answers that are garbage, questions that are garbage, garbage that is garbage, etc.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and agree in pretty much all of it. I just don't see why people flag clarifications of answers. That is the sole purpose of the comments to answers as far as I can see. And as you say if it had been 10 comments back and forth, or even five. Sure delete them, it's noise. But one single comment clarifying. +1 on this

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't worry too much about the OP. We're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming. Helping the OP is a nice side effect, but in this case the OP has already served their purpose by providing a question for the library, and they've apparently found the help they needed because they accepted an answer, so there's nothing more for them to do. The only influence they'll be able to have on the situation at this point is potentially changing the accepted answer, which doesn't really matter because both the answers work just fine.

It's good that you noticed your mistake and fixed it, because your answer is better for the library now. I upvoted it because I think it's a useful answer. But the OP noticing that you edited it is irrelevant in the big picture. I also added another answer knowing that the OP will probably never look at it. I think it's fine to leave a comment informing them that you already made the edit, but I think it's also fine for that comment to disappear at any time. I assume those comments back and forth happened within a few minutes, while the OP was still around, so they probably saw your comment. But even if they didn't, that comment was only ever going to be of any use to one person, and just noise to anyone else.

Comment: Agree. But I still don't think one clarifying comment to much to ask. The comments was about an hour apart, so OP did not see it. But you are right about the big picture.

Comment: No, I don't think it's too much to ask either. I think it's not too big a deal that it was flagged, but I wouldn't have flagged it myself. I probably would have a couple of years ago, being one of the overzealous people Cody was referring to, but I've relaxed about that since then, among other things, and I'm much happier for it.